# jquery.remoteChained while each, remain selected item on Edit Page

Tags: jquery, json, select, chained, city

```
   <div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-4"><label for="town">Town</label></div>
<div class="col-8"><select name="town" id="town" class="form-control form-control-sm">
<option value="<?php echo $adresdetay["TownID"];?>"><?php echo townName($adresdetay["townID"]);?></option>
</select></div>
</div>
</div>
```

if i each city, selected town (in my opened row/edit detail page) remain on select..
How you use remoteChained with in jquery or php-json page?